# Swift - Creating a Parse Class with an Object that is a Pointer to an object in another class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

Excuse me if this is already explained somewhere in Swift, I know it is simple but I simply can't find the answer anywhere.

So essentially my problem is that I have a class in Parse called "Groups" that has a "title" object in it. Then in the code below, I am creating a new class called "RankedItems" that has it's own objects. One of the objects is "groupOwner" and the objective here is to assign it to a pointer to the "title" object in the "Groups" class.

My code is listed below. Clearly I have the wrong syntax in the line of code that attempts to create "groupOwner", I have been trying everything so I figured I would leave that in as a placeholder.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should create "groupOwner" as a pointer to an object in the "Groups" class? Thanks!

```
 // Add Parse Group Object
        var itemRank:PFObject = PFObject(className: "RankedItems")

        itemRank["itemName"] = newItem
        itemRank["groupOwner"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Groups", objectId: "title")
        itemRank.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (success) {

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                println("Error adding group to parse")
            }
        }

        self.typedItems.append(newItem)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }))
```

Comment: You can't add a pointer to a particular field of a Parse object, just to the object itself, so you would simply assign the relevant `Group` `PFObject` to the `groupOwner` field

Comment: Thanks but my question is, what is the syntax to do that? The withoutDataWithClassName I'm using is clearly wrong.

Comment: `itemRank["groupOwner"]=aGroupsObject` where `aGroupsObject` is a PFObject that represents the group you want to point to - you would typically to retrieve it using a `PFQuery`

Comment: Hmm if anyone else has a suggestion let me know. I'm new to swift and that doesn't make sense to me haha.

Comment: Have you worked through the Parse tutorials?  Do you know how to retrieve an object from Parse?

Answer (score 0):

try this

// Add Parse Group Object
        var itemRank:PFObject = PFObject(className: "RankedItems")

```
    itemRank["itemName"] = newItem
    itemRank["groupOwner"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Groups", objectId: PFUser.current()?.objectId)
    itemRank.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if success {
                    // saved successfully


                } else {
                    // not error, and not saved for some reason... it could be impossible to reach this point
                }

            } else {

                // There was a problem, check error.description
                println("Error adding group to parse")
            }

    }

    self.typedItems.append(newItem)

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}))
```

I corrected

```
objectId: "Title"
```

to

```
objectId: PFUser.current()?.objectId
```